# Is it possible to "rollback" db:populate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I populated my development db with dummy data for 20 users using the Faker gem.

I forgot to include a "created_at" time, so they are now all ordered ahead of my hand-created detailed user records. I would like to either:

1) delete the 20 dummy users, and repopulate them with older "created_at" times, or

2) update the 20 dummy users' "created_at" attributes with older times.

Option 1 is easy enough if there is a way to undo my initial population rake. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails there is no option to remove data in database other than rake tasks.

In this case i think **option 1** is better one as there is **not much effort** to be put. Since created_at is updated automatically while creation of recored you need not do that. You just need to delete data from users table.

Just **type rails db** in project folder in terminal and there type following command

```
delete from users where id in ( select id from users order desc LIMIT 20)
```

It will delete last 20 users.

Create a **new migration** to add **created_at column** to table.

Run the **rake task**.

Everything will go perfect!

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Paritosh. I'm having issues with connecting to my db (psql) through the command line, but will do this as soon as I set it up. In the meantime, what would be the easiest way to delete the x most recent data records via the console? (I can actually delete via the PGAdminIII graphical interface, but was wondering if there's an easy way to do this through the rails console)

Comment: Definitely you can use rails console. Take your casse, you want to delete last 20 users. I am assuming that you have User model for users table, you can do it as

User.last(20).each do |u|;
  
  u.destroy;

end;

Comment: Thanks @Paritosh. Had forgotten to accept this. I see you have a typo `;` after the |u|.

Comment: @umezo Thanks, no it is not typo, actually u can write ruby like this in one line without line break. Here ';' represent line break and end of statement -:).

Comment: Thanks @Paritosh. For some reason, I can get `User.last(20).each do |u| u.destroy; end` to work, but can't get `User.last(20).each do |u|; u.destroy; end;` to work.